# Почему бот из бд достает мое сообщение, когда должен вывести другой ответ?

Tags: php, mysql, telegram-bot

Суть такая: пользователь через инлайн мод бота пишет @username и сообщение, которое хочет отправить. Бот сохраняет username того, кому отправляют, а также того, кто отправляет и само сообщение
После чего бот присылает сообщение с кнопкой, которую нажать может тот юзер, кому оно было адресовано, остальным же бот напишет, что чужое сообщение нельзя прочитать

Функция получения сообщения из бд:

```
function message_get($username)
{
    global $db;
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $username);
    $query = ("SELECT message, receiver_id
        FROM `secret_messages`
        WHERE receiver_id = '$username'
        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"); // Получить последний ID со строкой
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die ("Получить сообщение не удалось");
    return $result->fetch_assoc();
}
```

Сравнение юзернеймов получателя и того, кто нажимает на кнопку:

```
switch ($callback_data) {
case 'view_message':
    $messageData = message_get($username); // Получение запроса из бд
    if ($messageData['receiver_id'] == $username) { // Сравнение юзернейма/айди юзера, кому прислали сообщение и кто его читает
        $alert_message = [
            'callback_query_id' => $callback_query_id,
            'text' => $messageData['message'],
            'show_alert' => TRUE
        ];
        sendRequest('answerCallbackQuery', $alert_message);

        $message_read = [
            'inline_message_id' => $inline_message_id,
            'text' => '<b>Сообщение было прочитано</b> ✔',
            'parse_mode' => 'html'
        ];
        sendRequest('editMessageText', $message_read);
    } elseif ($messageData['message'] == null) {
        $alert_message = [
            'callback_query_id' => $callback_query_id,
            'text' => 'Такого сообщения не существует!',
            'show_alert' => TRUE
        ];
        sendRequest('answerCallbackQuery', $alert_message);
    } elseif ($messageData['receiver_id'] != $username) {
        $alert_message = [
            'callback_query_id' => $callback_query_id,
            'text' => 'Упс! Это не твое сообщение! ',
            'show_alert' => TRUE
        ];
        sendRequest('answerCallbackQuery', $alert_message);
    }
        break;
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что после отправления сообщения, для нажавшего на кнопку человека достается когда-то адресованное ему сообщение. Если в данный момент сообщение пришло не ему, то он все равно может нажать на кнопку, но прочитает только старый запрос

Пример на скриншотах:

[image: сообщение пришло мне]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: я могу его прочитать]

[image: сообщение не мне]

[image: вернулось ранее написанное мне сообщение]

В итоге следующая ситуация - я пишу себе сообщение test и спокойно его читаю, затем пишу сообщение человеку с другим username и при нажатии на кнопку возвращается мое предыдущее сообщение, а не выводится от бота - Это не твое сообщение

[image: что сохраняется в бд]

Как можно по другому оформить функцию, чтобы каждому пользователю возвращалось свое сообщение, а другим выводилось, что оно чужое?

Comment: не понимаю, где вообще в 2021 году можно прочитать про real_escape для передачи параметров.

Comment: @teran Наверное мне "повезло" наткнуться на первую ссылку с такой функцией, во всяком случае она работает

Answer (score 0):

```
$messageData = message_get($username); // Получение запроса из бд
if ($messageData['receiver_id'] == $username)
```

Смотри ты в функцию передаешь юзернэйм и получаешь строку где receiver_id равно этому юзернэйму, а потом берешь receiver_id в условии и сравниваешь с тем же юзернэймом с которым ты получил эту строку из базы. Понял? Условие всегда будет истина. Ты не можешь получить строку из базы где receiver_id=$username а потом в условии это ожидать что они будут отличаться

Comment: Да, я это понимаю, я использую подобную конструкцию, потому что она единственная отображает сообщения при нажатии на кнопку. До нее я пытался сравнить по `inline_query_id`, но понял, что они в боте не сохраняются и, соответственно, не проверяются, и делал проверку без `$username`, но мне просто возвращалось самое последнее сообщение, а при просмотре предыдущих чужих сообщений открывалось теперь уже только мое последнее. Поэтому я и думаю, с чем сделать проверку, чтобы пользователь, кому было адресовано сообщение, мог нажать на кнопку и прочитать сообщение, а остальные нет

Comment: можешь по подробнее рссказать как программа работает?

Comment: можешь по подробнее рссказать как программа работает? понимаешь если пользователь дуров нажмёт кнопку то из базы выйдет строка id=1515, и он увидит своё последнее сообщение. а если кнопку нажмёт пользователь  dur нажмёт ЭТУ ЖЕ кнопку он получит строку id=1514. И получается любой чел по кнопке видит своё последнее сообщение, которое возможно было ему по другой кнопке. Я бы как то помечал клики по кнопке что они уже прочитаны отправителем чтобы не выбирать их ещё раз.

Comment: так же я бы изменил условия. if ($messageData['receiver_id'] == $username) вот это алогичная проверка, если у тебя в запросе where receiver_id=$username. То зачем потом ещё раз их сравнивать. Если у тебя запрос вернул строку то значит она уже принадлежит тому челку который нажал на кнопку. Значит если у тебя запрос не пустой, то возвращаешь текст сообщения. Если он пустой, то это чужая кнопка, возвращаешь упс.

Comment: Насчет было ли прочитано сообщение или нет, я написал простое условие, что если человек, кому было написано сообщение, нажал на кнопку и прочитал сообщение, то бот редактирует сообщение на - "Сообщение было прочитано" (извиняюсь за тавтологию).
Насчет же изменения условия попробую удалить `if ($messageData['receiver_id'] == $username)`, чтобы оно не повторялось